# "Garnered" the attention of

Tags: word-usage

I've used this phrase a couple of times recently and it just now struck me that I'm not entirely sure if it's correct. I'm using it in pretty much the same context as "*caught the attention of*" or "*drew the attention of*."

Based on the dictionary definition of *garner*...

> > "gather or collect (something, especially information or approval)"

...it seems like people would know what I'm talking about, but I'm not sure if the word actually works here.

Both times I've used this phrase, it has been in the context of someone doing something fairly drastic and drawing the (potentially unwanted) attention of someone else. Am I using it correctly?

Comment: You quote it as meaning "*gather or collect*", but You you've used it in the context of "*caught/drew the attention of*".  Why?  If it means "*gather or collect*", why are use trying to use it in a different sense?  The obvious quick answer to your question is "No".

Comment: [This](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/garnered) may reassure you. I found it with [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=garnered+a+lot+of+attention&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22garnered+a+lot+of+attention%22).

Comment: @TrevorD I feel like it still applies though, because you're still "gaining" or "receiving" the attention, which pretty much means the same thing. At least in my mind.

Comment: and thanks, @BrianDonovan - that particular link doesn't really contain what I'm looking for, but some of the other results in that Google search look helpful.

Comment: "Gather/collect" is NOT the same as "gaining/receiving".  "Gathering/collecting" is *active*: the person is going out and gathering food, nuts, flowers, or whatever; or collecting souvenirs, coins, stamps, ... .  "Gaining/receiving" is *passive*: you sit there and receive presents from other people; you gain points by being awarded them by other people - yes, you may have done something to deserve the points given, but that is one step removed from receiving them.